# prevent flushing after merge in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

1.I have a complex entity with lazy associations. I load it to a property in my @Viewscoped bean (it is detached).

2.I change some fields in the entity (still detached).

3.Now i need the lazy objects from my entity, so i merge the entity to persistence context  and initialize the lazy objects like:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public MyEntity loadTheLazyObjects(MyEntity myEntity){
  //at the beginning myEntity is detached 
myEntity = entityManager.merge(myEntity) //it is managed now
myEntity.getSomeLazyCollection.size(); //initialize lazy collection
entityManager.clear(); //myEntity is detached again
return myEntity;
}
```

I need to merge the entity so i can load the lazy associations (i need active hibernate session) but i do not want the changes in my entity to be saved to the database. Thats why before the end of the transaction i detach it from persistence context. Will it help?

I do not want any SQL UPDATES on myEntity when the transaction is finished, and i guess hibernate will prepare the object to update after merge, so does detaching the object prevent hibernate from firing updates before the end of transaction? Can the flush be called during the merge?

Comment: You could argue that, since the objects are lazy loaded in this way, you might as well create a seperate query to retrieve them.

I don't know how to NOT update the entity using merge.

Comment: The purpose of merge is to merge. If you need some sort of combined object. Load the responsible object from the database and merge them on your own. f.e. ModelMapper

Comment: instead of `merge()`, you can `em.find()` corresponding entity (it will be managed until `em.clear()`) and take a collection from there.

Comment: i will do so. thank you for your anwers.

Answer (score 4):

`merge` will never trigger any implicit `flush`. Flushing only occurs in the following three situations:

1. Before query execution (HQL/JPQL and native queries) in cases when Hibernate concludes that the executed query may be working with stale data in the database.
2. When `flush` is called explicitly.
3. When transaction is committed.

If you want to be absolutely sure that no flushing will occur (unless you explicitly call it, of course), set the flush mode to [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#MANUAL):

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
```

JPA flush mode does not support manual option, that's why Hibernate native `Session` API has to be used.

This way you don't need to clear the persistence context after merging, no changes are flushed anyway.